# SQL join and count rows (count people in table)

Tags: sql

I have a table with users and a table with their posts. I do not understand how to calculate the number of users, for example, whose number of posts is less than 10.

```
select Users.DisplayName, count(Users.id) as Questions from Users
LEFT JOIN
Posts on Users.id=Posts.OwnerUserId
GROUP BY Users.DisplayName
HAVING (count(Users.Id)<10) or (count(Users.Id)>10 and count(Users.Id)<20)
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  You should also include your complete query as *text* in the question.

Comment: What columns are in the `Posts` table?

Comment: Id, OwnerUserId

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1317468#resultSets - that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *number* of users that have less than 10 records, than you can simply use a [`COUNT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(a.DisplayName)
  
FROM
    Users a
        LEFT JOIN Posts b ON a.id = b.OwnerUserId

HAVING
    COUNT(b.Id) < 10
```

[You can see that here using the data explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1317468#resultSets)

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1317468#resultSets - that data

Comment: I do not need the whole table, maybe I did not correctly put the question, but the number of rows in this table on your request, that is, how to count all the rows where the questions are less than ten

Comment: Corrected @TheNoName

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please accept this answer so that others may find it useful @TheNoName

Comment: I apologize for my English maybe something is wrong again. I wrote the same request, but I can't understand how to do this:

Output:
more than 10
for example 123123 rows

Comment: I don't understand what you want as an output. The number of users that have 10 or more questions?

Comment: like SELECT * FROM TABLE -> n rows,  not the list itself

Comment: See my answer @TheNoName